# Does Scipy linalg.eig produce all possible eigenvectors?

Tags: python, scipy, eigenvector

I have this matrix `a` -

```
array([[2, 1],
       [1, 2]])
```

This matrix has `[1, 3]` eigenvalues and following eigenvectors:

```
array([1, -1])
array([1, 1])
```

But when I use Scipy's `linalg.eig` function, it produces following results:

```
>>>  linalg.eig(a)
(array([3.+0.j, 1.+0.j]), array([[ 0.70710678, -0.70710678],
    [ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]]))
```

The eigenvalues are same as above but eigenvectors produced here are different from those mentioned earlier.

What am I missing here? Also, how to find out the number of eigenvectors a matrix can have?

Comment: the eigenvectors are *normalized*; what you are seeing is `1/sqrt(2)` times the eigenvectors you expect. as any multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, this is the convenction that is usually adapted by libraries.

Comment: Probably your eigenvectors are rounded, because answer of the function is correct

Comment: @hiro 
protagonist That seems to be the case. Just read the docs 
carefully and it actually said function would return normalized eigenvectors.

Comment: @Alex No. As mentioned in another comment, function returns normalized eigenvectors. Scipy docs also mentions about normalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Can you answer your question and accept it so we can close this?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes. Will do that in a while.

Answer (score 0):

There are infinitely many eigenvectors for each eigenvalue. Namely, if `v` is an eigenvector and `a` any nonzero number, then `a*v` is also an eigenvector. Thus, it is impossible for any program to return all eigenvectors. What they do is return a maximal set of [*linearly independent*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) eigenvectors. Such a set can be chosen in many ways.

For eigenvalues with geometric multiplicity 1 (i.e., one-dimensional eigenspace) there is an almost canonical choice: return an eigenvector of norm 1.  There is still a degree of arbitrariness here, because if `u` is a normalized eigenvector, so is `-u`. Which one is chosen depends on the details of the algorithm and may vary from one linear algebra package to another.

For eigenvalues with geometric multiplicity greater than 1 (i.e., an eigenspace of 2 or more dimensions) the degree of arbitrariness is even greater. Consider the matrix

```
2 0 
0 2
```

*Every* nonzero vector is an eigenvector for this matrix. Any two linearly independent vectors can be an answer here. (As of now SciPy returns the most obvious choice: [0, 1] and [1, 0] - but this is not a guarantee.)

In a linear algebra course one may have been taught to choose an *orthonormal* basis for each eigenspace. For better or for worse, SciPy wasn't: when an eigenspace has dimension greater than 1, the basis it picks for it is not necessarily orthonormal. An example is the matrix

```
1 2 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

where I threw in "2" to make it non-symmetric.

```
from scipy.linalg import eig
import numpy as np
m = np.ones((4, 4))
m[0, 1] = 2
evals, evecs = eig(m)
print(np.around(evals, 2))
print(np.around(evecs, 2))
```

prints eigenvalues `[-0.24,  4.24, 0, 0]` and the corresponding eigenvectors

```
[[-0.88  0.58 -0.77 -0.77]
 [ 0.27  0.47 -0.   -0.  ]
 [ 0.27  0.47  0.61  0.16]
 [ 0.27  0.47  0.16  0.61]]
```

The last two eigenvectors come from the same eigenspace (0, with multiplicity 2) so they could have been chosen to be orthogonal to each other, but SciPy did not do that.